# Jira plugin for Jenkins is not woking?

Tags: java, jenkins, jira, jenkins-plugins, jira-plugin

Hi I am trying to post the build failure status to jira from jenkins. I am using Jenkins 1.588 and jira plugin 1.39 I have configured the jenkis to use my jira account. Its not working. I am hosting jenkins in Apache Tomcat 7.0.14 and my java version is 1.7. I am getting the logs as follows.The issue is not creating in jira....please help.

```
Nov 13, 2014 10:25:28 AM org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair convertJSON
WARNING: 'stapler-class' is deprecated: hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater
Nov 13, 2014 10:25:29 AM org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair convertJSON
WARNING: 'stapler-class' is deprecated: hudson.plugins.jira.JiraCreateIssueNotif
ier
Nov 13, 2014 10:25:29 AM org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair convertJSON
WARNING: 'stapler-class' is deprecated: hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater
Nov 13, 2014 10:25:29 AM org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair convertJSON
WARNING: 'stapler-class' is deprecated: hudson.plugins.jira.JiraCreateIssueNotif
ier
There is no such file...!!
Nov 13, 2014 10:25:53 AM javax.jmdns.impl.DNSIncoming readAnswer
WARNING: There was an OPT answer. Not currently handled. Option code: 65002 data
: 5BAD035FB714EB55
Nov 13, 2014 10:25:53 AM javax.jmdns.impl.DNSIncoming readAnswer
WARNING: There was an OPT answer. Not currently handled. Option code: 65002 data
: 5BAD035FB714EB55
Nov 13, 2014 10:25:54 AM javax.jmdns.impl.DNSIncoming readAnswer
WARNING: There was an OPT answer. Not currently handled. Option code: 65002 data
: 5BAD035FB714EB55
Nov 13, 2014 10:25:56 AM javax.jmdns.impl.DNSIncoming readAnswer
WARNING: There was an OPT answer. Not currently handled. Option code: 65002 data
: 5BAD035FB714EB55
Nov 13, 2014 10:26 0 AM javax.jmdns.impl.DNSIncoming readAnswer
WARNING: There was an OPT answer. Not currently handled. Option code: 65002 data
: 5BAD035FB714EB55
Nov 13, 2014 10:26 4 AM org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler
SEVERE: failed to execute
```

Answer (score 1):

```
java -Dhudson.DNSMultiCast.disabled=true

/usr/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhudson.DNSMultiCast.disabled=true -jar /Applications/Jenkins/jenkins.war
```

See also: http://favoorr.github.io/mac-os-x-jenkins-auto-running-on-startup/